# How to fix the 'IndexError: list index out of range' in a couple of arrays and how to create a non-defined multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was making a permutation script with python an i looked for how to make a multidimensional array, but the only way i could find was `array3
 = [ [ "" for i in range(12) ] for j in range(4) ]` Is there any way i can make it so it's defined as multidimensional but not the size of it? I also found that it's possible to make it like `array = [[]]`but i cant find the way to put anything inside.
I'm trying to put letters and words inside the array so i think i cant use numpy.
For the other problem, the index out of range, I'm trying this:

```
array = [ ["a","b","c","d","e","f"],["7","8","9","0","11","12"]]
array2 = [ ["1","2","3","4","5","6"],["g","h","i","j","k","l"]]
array3 = [ [ "" for i in range(12) ] for j in range(4) ]
i,j = 0,0
print(array[0][0] + array2[0][1])
for k in range(3):
    for l in range(2):
        for m in range(4):
            for n in range(7):
                if j > 5:
                    j = 0
                    i += 1
                print(m,n,k,l,i,j)
                array3[m][n] =array[k][l] + array2[i][j]
                j += 1
print(array3)
```

I was trying to put the first multidimensional array and the second together with a permutation algorithm but it says that the index is out of range... 
What i want it to print is: a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, ag, ah, aj, ak, al, b1, b2...

Comment: Do you only care what gets printed OR do you want `array3` to have a specific structure? - Is `array3` a list of lists or just a single list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import chain, product

for first, second in product(chain.from_iterable(array),
                             chain.from_iterable(array2)):
    print("{}{}".format(first, second))
```

Since `array` and `array2` are lists and not arbitrary iterables, you can shorten this by using `chain` itself with argument unpacking:

```
for first, second in product(chain(*array), chain(*array2)):
    print("{}{}".format(first, second))
```

---

`array3` can be created as a flat list:

```
array3 = ["{}{}".format(first, second) for first, second in product(chain(*array), chain(array2))]
```

or as a nested list:

```
array3 = [["{}{}".format(first, second) for second in chain(*array2)] for first in chain(*array)]
```

Comment: It works perfectly but i have a syntax question. why did you put the * in front of the variable array?

Comment: `chain` takes one or more iterables as its arguments. `[[...], [...]]` would be considered a *single* iterable, so `chain(array)` would be somewhat of a no-op. Unpacking `array` like this is equivalent to `chain(array[0], array[1])`, so that chaining together its elements produces a "flattened" version of the original.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly You'll need a 4th degree nesting:

```
array = [["a","b","c","d","e","f"],["7","8","9","0","11","12"]]
array2 = [["1","2","3","4","5","6"],["g","h","i","j","k","l"]]

for row in array:  # iterate "rows"
    for cell in row:  # iterate "cells" in a specific "row"
        for row_2 in array2:
            for cell_2 in row_2:
                print '{}{}'.format(cell, cell_2)
```

which will give you:

```
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
a6
ag
ah
ai
aj
ak
al
b1
b2
b3
b4
b5
...
```

Comment: I'd use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to eliminate two of the explicit loops. `for j in from_iterable(array): for y in from_iterable(array2): ...`